# #between? error or anomaly in Cooper's *Beginning Ruby*

Tags: ruby

In Cooper's book *Beginning Ruby*, page 166 there's an example I'm unable to reproduce.

```
class Song
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :length
  def <=>(other)
    @length <=> other.length
  end

  def initialize(song_name, length)
    @song_name = song_name
    @length = length
  end
end

a = Song.new('Rock around the clock', 143)
b = Song.new('Bohemian Rhapsody', 544)
c = Song.new('Minute Waltz', 60)

a.between?(b, c)
```

In the book, it says the result should be `=> true` while I'm getting `=> false`.

I went on to break it down to...

```
puts 143.between?(544, 60) # => false
puts 143.between?(60, 544) # => true
```

And according to ruby-doc.org, it's supposed to be written as `between?(min,max)` -- which leads me to believe

- a) the book has a mistake
- b) in an earlier version of Ruby, between?
  was more flexible and allowed `(max,min)`
- c) this example is somehow anomalous and I'm
  missing something

Which is it?

Comment: ... basically *a)*...

Comment: Doesn't the book say which Ruby version it is based on? If so, you can compare it with DRoc of that version. I guess it is a).

Comment: Hi there! Author checking in :-) I just looked it up in the 2009 edition (edition 2, the latest at present, although edition 3 is due next year) and the example shows it as a.between?(c, b), so it works correctly. However, I can't check if edition 1 (2007) had the error you're reporting until I'm in the office next as I may have a copy there.. :-) Edition 2 can be seen in PDF for at http://no.gd/begruby22.pdf BTW.

Comment: The author's correct--thought I had the 2009 ed, but turns out I've been using the 2007 ed. that @ndn mentions finding in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been covered in some comments above, but as the author of the book I wanted to clarify that the 2009 edition (edition 2) of the book had this issue corrected. The original poster has updated that they were reading the 2007 edition :-)

As a definitive answer to the question, however, yes, the first edition of the book was in error.

Answer (score 4):

After a quick investigation, it looks like it's just a mistake in the book (if you are quoting it correctly).

I found the book as pdf [here](https://github.com/da99/my_lib/blob/master/programming/ruby/Apress-Beginning%20Ruby%20-%20From%20Novice%20to%20Professional.pdf). Unfortunately, page 166 is missing. However, on page 5, it says:

> In the "Ruby on Windows" section, you'll see a few links for different versions of Ruby you can download for Windows. Ideally you want to download the file at the link that's **highest** in the list that's referred to as a "One-Click Installer." **At the time of writing, this version is 1.8.5.**

Checking [CRuby's 1.8.5 `Comparable` implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_8_5/compar.c#L174), you can clearly see that  `between?` works the way it does today.

Comment: I was able to find a pdf that contained page 166 / 167, and it does appear the OP is quoting that part correctly.

Comment: Paul: Where? I just looked it up in the 2009 edition (edition 2) and the example shows as a.between?(c, b), so it works correctly. I can't check if edition 1 had the error though as I don't have that PDF, so I'd be keen to see if it was an edition 1 error we fixed back in 2009 :-) Edition 2 can be seen in PDF for at http://no.gd/begruby22.pdf BTW.

Comment: @PeterCooper Hi Peter, the pdf I found was [here](ftp://ftp.cmpe.emu.edu.tr/COURSES/Cmpe418/Apress%20-%20Beginning%20Ruby%20-%20From%20Novice%20to%20Professiona%20(2007).pdf). Looks like its the 2007 version I found. Here's an [image of the page in question](http://imgur.com/9vGvYvz). It looks like the error was indeed corrected between editions! :)

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to show you this. This is the C-source for the [`between?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) method:

```
               static VALUE
cmp_between(VALUE x, VALUE min, VALUE max)
{
    if (RTEST(cmp_lt(x, min))) return Qfalse;
    if (RTEST(cmp_gt(x, max))) return Qfalse;
    return Qtrue;
}
```

While I didn't look at every single version, I believe this method has remained unchanged since Ruby 1.8.7.

The `cmp_lt` and `cmp_gt` in plain english are "compare less than" and "compare greater than".

So as you can see, the method will return false if the value `x`, which in your case would be your `a` objects length of 144, is **less than the min**, which would be `b`'s length of 544. Since 144 < 544, you're getting the correct answer, and it does appear that the book contains a mistake.

I can't seem to determine whether this error has ever been reported before, so if you're inclined, it might be good to contact the author and let him know.

Comment: `cmp_lt` and `cmp_gt` don't mean "compare less than" and "compare greater than". They mean "less than on the Comparable module", and "greater than on the Comparable module".